# Olimex Lora-STM32WL-devkit + STM32CubeIDE = "Could not verify ST device!" How to check if device is genuine?

Tags: stm32cubeide, openocd, lora, lorawan

Devkit is not recognized as a genuine ST Device!

OpenOCD gives:

```
openocd -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -c "cmsis_dap_vid_pid 0x15ba 0x0044" -c "transport select swd" -c "adapter speed 1000" -f "target/stm32wlx.cfg"
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0 (2023-06-21) [https://github.com/sysprogs/openocd]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
libusb1 09e75e98b4d9ea7909e8837b7a3f00dda4589dc3
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
swd
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
none separate
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : CMSIS-DAP: SWD supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: FW Version = 1.0
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface Initialised (SWD)
Info : SWCLK/TCK = 1 SWDIO/TMS = 1 TDI = 0 TDO = 0 nTRST = 0 nRESET = 1
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface ready
Info : clock speed 500 kHz
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x6ba02477
Info : [stm32wlx.cpu0] Cortex-M4 r0p1 processor detected
Info : [stm32wlx.cpu0] target has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for stm32wlx.cpu0 on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
```

So: STM32WLE/WL5x - Rev '**unknown**' : 0x1001.

"unknown" is strange, no?

Then in STM32CubeIDE: Run->Debug (F11)

```
OpenOCD:

    Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
    Info : device idcode = 0x10016497 (STM32WLE/WL5x - Rev 'unknown' : 0x1001)
    Info : RDP level 0 (0xAA)
    Info : flash size = 256 KiB
    Info : flash mode : single-bank
    Info : device idcode = 0x10016497 (STM32WLE/WL5x - Rev 'unknown' : 0x1001)
    Info : RDP level 0 (0xAA)
    Info : OTP size is 1024 bytes, base address is 0x1fff7000
    undefined debug reason 8 (UNDEFINED) - target needs reset
    Info : dropped 'gdb' connection (error -400)
    Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
    undefined debug reason 8 (UNDEFINED) - target needs reset
    Info : dropped 'gdb' connection (error -400)
```

STM32CubeIDE shows a popup:

"Could not verify ST device! Please verify that the latest version of the GDB-server is used for the connection."

How to check if my Olimex Lora-STM32WL-devkit is genuine or not?

Thanks.

```
    STM32CubeIDE v1.12.1
    Olimex Lora-STM32WL-devkit Rev. D
    OpenOCD v0.12.0
```

Trying to build, modify and debug Olimex sample code using STM32CubeIDE and Olimex Lora-STM32WL-devkit.